# Query ActiveRecord for records and relation calculations at once

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**TL;DR? See Edit 2**

I've got a little Rails application that has a few different sort of games people can play: it's based around sports, so they can pick the winners of each game every week (model `PickEm`, attribute `correct` boolean with `nil` for unfinished games), and predict the outcome of a specific team's game (model `Guess`, attribute `score` with integer, `nil` for unfinished games). Every `User` `has_many` `PickEms` and `Guesses`. And I'm trying to display standings (`correct`/total - total being all non-`nil`, `score`/total possible).

What I'm finding is that I can gather the users and their associated records, but in trying to display standings I'm discovering that every single User is triggering another query - slow and not sustainable as the user base increases. That's because `@user.pick_em_score` is `pick_ems.where(correct: true).size` and `@user.guess_Score` is `guesses.where.not(score: nil).sum(:score)`. So I call `user.pick_em_score` and it runs that query. I feel like there should be a way to get every `User`, as well as these specific counts, at once, rather than buffering a whole bunch of needless extra stuff.

What I need:

- `User` record
- `User.pick_em_score` (calculated by counting `correct` records)
- `User.pick_ems` count where `NOT NULL`
- `User.guesses_score` (calculated by `guesses.sum(:score)`)
- `User.guesses` count where `NOT NULL`

Most of the stuff I find on Rails's ActiveRecord helpers, especially related to calculations, is for retrieving *only* the calculation. It looks like I'll probably need to delve directly into `select()` etc. But I can't get it working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

#### Edit

For clarification: I'm aware that I can write this information to the `User` model, but this is overly restrictive: next season, I'll need to add a new column to the `User` for *that* year's results, etc. In addition, this is a third degree of callback updating related models – the `Match` model already updates related `PickEms` and `Guesses` on save. **I'm looking for the simplest ActiveRecord query or queries to be able to work with this information, as indicated by the title.** Ideally one query that returns the above information, but if it needs to a few, that's OK.

I used to work directly in MySQL with PHP, but those skills have rusted (in raw MySQL, I imagine, I'd have several sub-select statements to help pull these counts) and I'd also *like* to be able to use Rails's ActiveRecord helpers and such, and avoid constructing raw SQL as much as possible.

### Second Edit:

**I seem to have it down to one call that *starts* to work, but I'm writing a lot of SQL.** It's also brittle, IMO, and trying to run with it has failed. It also looks like I'm just pushing the million singular `SELECT` queries from Rails right into SQL, but that may still be a step up.

```ruby
User.unscoped.select('users.*',
  '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pick_ems WHERE pick_ems.user_id = users.id AND pick_ems.correct) AS correct_pick_ems',
  '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pick_ems WHERE pick_ems.user_id = users.id AND pick_ems.correct IS NOT NULL) AS total_pick_ems',
  '(SELECT SUM(guesses.score) FROM guesses WHERE guesses.user_id = users.id AND guesses.score IS NOT NULL) AS guesses_score',
  '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM guesses WHERE guesses.user_id = users.id AND guesses.score IS NOT NULL) AS guesses_count' )
```

The issue seems to be: **is there a way to use Rails, and not raw SQL, to link up `users.id` that we see there with these subqueries**? Or just … a better way to construct this, in general?

In addition, I'm running another set of `SELECT`s for the `WHERE`, which would hinge on `total_pick_ems` and `guesses_count` being `> 0` but since I can't use those aliased columns, I have to call the `SELECT` one more time.

Comment: You might investigate using database views? I've never actually tried to use them but they can be represented in rails with a model as if they were an actual table.  I would consider making a database view that is basically your select statement and then associating one with the user... they might be a postgres thing though...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AR. Its really only good for simple CRUD like queries. Once you actually want to query your data in anger it just doesn't have the capababilities to do the queries you want without resorting to wholesale SQL strings and often abandoning the ability to chain as a result.

Its precisely why I moved to Sequel as it does have the features to compose queries using a much fuller SQL feature set, including join conditions, window functions, recursive common table expressions, and advanced eager loading. The author is incredibly responsive and documentation is excellent compared to AR and Arel.

I don't expect you will like this answer but a time will come when you will start to look outside the opinionated components that come with rails which I have to say are hardly best of breed. Sequel also sped my application up many times over what I was able to get with AR as well, it not just developer happiness, it means less servers to run. Yes it will be a learning curve but IMO its better to learn tools that have your back covered.

Comment: Had not heard of Sequel. I will have to check it out, thanks. Doesn't solve my problem here, but it's intriguing at least.

Answer (score 1):

Joins might work. Smthing like below

```
User.unscoped.joins(:guesses).joins(:pick_ems).
where("guesses.score IS NOT NULL").
select("users.*, 
sum(guesses.score) as guesses_score,
count(guesses.id) as guesses_count,
count(case when pick_ems.correct = True then 1 else null end) 
as correct_pick_ems,
count(case when pick_ems.correct != null then 1 else null end)
as total_pick_ems,
").
group("users.id")
```

If you need this information for a limited number of users at a time then above query or eager loading (`User.includes(:guesses, :pick_ems)`) with class methods like

```
def correct_pick_ems
   pick_ems.count(&:correct)
end
```

would work.

However If you need this information for all the users most of the time, cached counters within the users table would be more optimal.

Comment: Almost there! This is what I was looking for, but it appears to be multiplying because of the two joins. I've got that problem solved for the guesses_count (using `DISTINCT`), but not the others. Here's what I've got: `User.unscoped.joins(:guesses, :pick_ems).select('users.*, sum(guesses.score) as guesses_score, count(DISTINCT guesses.id) as guesses_count, sum(case when pick_ems.correct = true then 1 else 0 end) as correct_pick_ems, sum(case when pick_ems.correct IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as total_pick_ems').where.not(guesses: { score: nil }, pick_ems: { correct: nil }).group('users.id')`

Comment: Awarding the bounty here. This is the closest to what I was looking for. FTR I already have the User methods all set up, but that's not practical when trying to get *every* User's info (it creates at least one SQL call for each).

Comment: @BenSaufley If you use eager loading it would make 3 sql calls overall. One to get all the users `Users`, next two  to get all associated the `guesses` and `pick_ems`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: It doesn't, because it needs to query the guesses and pick_ems for each user. The Users may have their associated records pre-queried, but the count functions don't go through Ruby, they run their own SQL queries.

Comment: @BenSaufley that is correct. `count` would make a another SQL call but that canbe easily correct by using `length` instead of `count`

Comment: well, yeah, I could use `size` or `length` to avoid the SQL call if I wanted all of them, but the `count` SQL call involves a conditional. Right? count where correct? Could do `.select(&:correct?).length` but that's less optimal, especially for one-off queries, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some sort of custom (smart) counter_cache to count only at certain conditions (e.g correct is true)

You can achive this using [conditional](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks) `after_save` & `after_destroy` triggers to build your own custom counter_cache that looks like this:

```
class PickEm
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :increment_finished_counter_cache, if: Proc.new { |pick_em| pick_em.correct }
  after_destroy :decrement_finished_counter_cache, if: Proc.new { |pick_em| pick_em.correct }

  private

  def increment_finished_counter_cache
    self.user.update_column(:finished_games_counter, self.user.finished_games_counter + 1) #update_column should not trigger any validations or callbacks
  end

  def decrement_finished_counter_cache
    self.user.update_column(:finished_games_counter, self.user.finished_games_counter - 1) #update_column should not trigger any validations or callbacks
  end
end
```

#### Notes:

- Code not tested (only to show the idea)
- Some guys said it's better to avoid naming custom counters as rails name them (foo_counter_cache)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this possible solution, but I'm already doing a similar thing on the game modules – when `Match` is updated, it updates `PickEm` and `Guess` with scoring - and I'd like to avoid keeping so much of this stuff that can be programmatically-determined written into the database. Plus, next season, I'd have to create `finished_games_counter_2015` to keep new scores. I'm looking for the ActiveRecord solution with the fewest/simplest SQL queries.

Comment: Too many conditions for an answer :) i think you better update your question to get better answers!

Comment: I thought the title and question were pretty explicitly about ActiveRecord queries, but I have added clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should benchmark it, but my hunch is that adding all of that data into a single `SELECT` isn't going to be much faster than breaking it up into separate `SELECT`s (I've actually had cases where the latter was faster). By breaking it up, you can also stick to more ActiveRecord and less raw SQL, e.g.:

```
user_ids_to_pick_em_score = User.joins(:pick_ems).where(pick_ems: {correct: true}).group(:user_id).count
user_ids_to_pick_ems_count = User.joins(:pick_ems).where.not(pick_ems: {correct: nil}).group(:user_id).count
user_ids_to_guesses_score = Hash[User.select("users.id, SUM(guesses.score) AS total_score").joins(:guesses).group(:user_id).map{|u| [u.id, u.total_score]}]
user_ids_to_guesses_count = User.joins(:guesses).where.not(guesses: {score: nil}).group(:user_id).count
```

**Edit**: To display them, you could do like so:

```
<%- User.select(:id, :name).find_each do |u| -%>
  Name: <%= u.name %>
  Picks Correct: <%= user_ids_to_pick_em_score[u.id] %>/<%= user_ids_to_pick_ems_count[u.id] %>
  Total Score: <%= user_ids_to_guesses_score[u.id] %>/<%= user_ids_to_guesses_count[u.id] %>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: I can tell you that Heroku (on the free tier) was running out of memory trying to run each query by itself for each User, and my current solution actually runs surprisingly quickly. Your solution may be the best answer (fewer SELECTs, less raw SQL/more Ruby), but now they're in four separate relations that aren't programmatically linked. When I go to iterate through Users to display standings, I have to search b/w relations to match them up… right?

Comment: Each of the lines above will give you a hash of user IDs to the desired values (pick_em score, count, etc.). If you want them all in one query, I'm afraid there's no way to do this in AR. I'm surprised that these solutions cause any memory issues; all but the third don't instantiate any AR objects, which tend to be the memory hogs in Rails. I run similar queries on my DB of over 200,000 records and get results in around 50ms.

Comment: These queries are not creating memory issues, nor is mine, above. The original solution (get Users with pick_ems or guesses, iterate through them and display info) caused a new query for each time a user displayed (to get the user's score) and apparently filled up Heroku's memory.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes more sense. If you still see performance issues with these, you could try caching them as model methods so you don't have to calculate them on each page load.